# Asp.Net MVC 5 Selecting Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to show active announcements in my home page.

**This is my Model:**

```
public class Duyuru {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Mesaj")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Başlık")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Aktif")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
//if i don't do this static, it's giving an error.
public class Announcement{
    public static List<Duyuru> GetDuyuru(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        try {
            var feeds = from feed in db.Duyuru.ToList()
                        select new Duyuru {
                            Title = feed.Title,
                            Message = feed.Message,
                            ID = feed.ID,
                            Active = feed.Active        
                        };        
            return feeds.ToList();
        } catch (Exception) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my View:**

```
@model Tuple<.. , .. , List<DT_Muhasebe.Models.Duyuru>>
     <table class="table table-hover">

          @{
             counter = 0;
             try{
               foreach (var item in Model.Item3){
                 if (item.Active == true){
                   <tr><td><a href="Duyuru/Details/@item.ID">@item.Title</a></td></tr>
                   counter += 1;
                 }
                 if (counter == 6) { break; }
                }
              } catch (Exception) {
                <tr><td>Yeni duyuru bulunmamaktadır.</td></tr>
              }
            }
        </table>
```

**This is my HomeController:**

```
var allModels = new Tuple<.. , .. , List<Duyuru>>(.., .. ,
RssReaderController.Announcement.GetDuyuru(db).OrderByDescending(e => e.UploadDate));
return View(allModels);
```

This code is not working for some reason. I hope someone can help.The reason why get it from RssReasderController instead of DuyuruController is if i make the ApplicationDbContext static, other features like Create or Edit is not working and if i don't do it static i am getting an error in GetDuyuru since it's static and db.Duyuru is not. If i make the GetDuyuru class non-static then it's giving an error in HomeController

Comment: why `dbcontext` class static what error comes if you remove `static` keyword

Comment: Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DT_Muhasebe.Controllers.RssReaderController.db

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER... EVER make a DbContext Static in a web application.  Web apps are multi-user, and multi-threaded.  Static data is shared between users and threads and DbContexts are not thread safe by their nature.  For instance, if you add an entity to your DbContext, another user might also be adding an entity and call SaveChanges when you aren't expecting it, or you could be stomping on each others caches.  There is no way to mitigate this, just don't ever make a DbContext static in a web application.  You can do so in a Windows forms or console app.

Comment: in this case only admins will be able to add new data, also I've tryed to make it non-static but it gave some errors.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can have more than one admin and it's still a problem.  It can cause data corruption.  Never do it.

Comment: it doesn't matter, In addition to the data corruption, statics exist for the lifetime of the application, and DbContexts have no mechanism to clean themselves up or prune their caches other than by garbage collection when deleted.  So your DbContext will continue to consume memory, and grow in consumption until your app pool is recycled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, never post a question to Stack Overflow and say "it gives me an error" and then neglect to say what error it is.  Stack Overflowers don't like psychic debugging (trying to figure out important things you didn't bother to tell them).

Second, the problem is that static methods have no state.  They can't access member objects because there is no instance for them to access.  So any data they access must also be static.

The solution to your problem is to create a new context (which you should always do anyways)

```
using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    //  your code
}
```

One important thing, since the DbContext will get disposed at the end of the call, you need to make sure the query executes completely before returning.

```
return feeds.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i uptaded my question. Next time I will be more carefull when i will ask a question.